# cannot find symbol symbol: class SparkReporter on jhipster application

Tags: java, maven, jhipster

I created a jhipster applicaiton, when i run it over inllijIdea i got this error :

> Error:(126, 25) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class SparkReporter
>     location: class com.qemweb.tese2.config.MetricsConfiguration

Comment: Please show the..yo-rc.json file in your project

Comment: `{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "baseName": "cmdval",
    "packageName": "com.qemweb.cmdval",
    "packageFolder": "com/qemweb/cmdval",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "no",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "no",
    "useCompass": true,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "frontendBuilder": "grunt",
    "javaVersion": "8",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "rememberMeKey": "46c4f98ed44c484653a5a12b09aef8e9a27cb397"
  }
}`

Comment: Please add that to your question. Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what do you want me to add ?

Answer (score 0):

SparkReporter class comes from metrics-spark-reporter which is a required dependency when using JHipster in java 8, if you look at your generated pom.xml you should see:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>fr.ippon.spark.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-spark-reporter</artifactId>
        <version>${metrics-spark-reporter.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

For some reason, it seems IntelliJ did not succeed to download this dependency.
Could you try running the application from maven?

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Comment: with mvn spring-boot:run i got the same error : `..../config/MetricsConfiguration.java:[150,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SparkReporter  location: class ....config.MetricsConfiguration.SparkRegistry
[ERROR] .../config/MetricsConfiguration.java:[151,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SparkReporter`

Comment: Yes but haven't you got an error earlier in the maven trace? Have you verified that your pom.xml contains the dependecy I quoted above?

Comment: yes i verfied it contains the dependency !! and here the full stack [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14e-sXANZ4-IksT7CJ-8yohWCG_7KXElZ_BKxHTz1j4I/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you show the output of `mvn dependency:tree` and your pom.xml?

Comment: the pom.xml : [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hT1hwrrO1UbT36RI_XW0GjuhnIvTs4OSmdxNFT7pjKo/edit?usp=sharing) 
the mvn dependency:tree : [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KgAqoaBOg6_ANJ1pN4vgkfLx-tpW9_3Dk_1-zldMjjU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your pom seems correct. I suspect your maven local repository is corrupted, you can try to see the size of the jars and check SHA1 in ~/.m2/repository/fr/ippon/spark/metrics/metrics-spark-reporter/ and you'd better delete this directory and restart a maven build*; Anyway this is nota JHipster issue.

Comment: i tried to generate several projects, and i have the same issue each time !! i tried to delete as you said and have the same issue !!

Comment: If you think it's a JHipster isue (which is highly improbable), generate a project, share it on github.com and if i can't compile it, I will work on it as a JHipster contributor. For the moment, everything points to a problem in your environment.